# How to stop the child to inheriting the parents filter property?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I use the css `filter` property on the parent then It affecting the child too. I want to stop the child to not effect when I set the propert `filter` in parent.

```css
article {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  
  position: relative;
}

article:hover {
  filter: contrast(110%);
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #FCDBA3;
  
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" />
  
  <div></div>
</article>
```

If you noticed carefully! You can see when I hover over the article then the div tag also affecting because of the filter property. But I don't want the div to get affected when I hover over the article.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Every child is part of the parent, you cannot apply a filter to the parent without also affecting the children. Make the child a sibling instead.

Answer (score 3):

As far i understood you want to make hover effect **in** article tag but excluding the div element for that you can use this

```
article :not(div):hover{
  filter: contrast(110%);
}
```

instead of

```
article:hover {
  filter: contrast(110%);
}
```

Comment: This won't work in case of children

Comment: didn't get you can you elaborate?

Comment: It's working  But the Question is, why is it working? Just a single space between article and :not() works out. But why? Can you explain it?

Comment: basically, what you mention in :not pseudo-class gets excluded from the selection so in the above selector we are just mentioning to go in the article and apply hover if and only if the element is not equal to div you can read more about :not pseudo class [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other helpful answers, since technically your question is "How to stop the child to inheriting the parents filter property?" the answer is that the child elements don't *inherit* the property but are *affected* by it, and there is no way to prevent it other than applying the filter to another element (as suggested on other answers).

To give an example with something similar but simpler, if you apply the `opacity` property with a value lower than `1` to an element, then there is no way for any child element to get a higher opacity than their parent element.

Comment: Well, Abbas' answers [seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/kgaj4012/) with `filter` (and also with `opacity`) ..?

Comment: Yeah because they apply the filter to one of the child elements rather than to the parent element, which is sufficinet in this specific case. But applying the filter to a parent and excluding the childs - is not possible.

Comment: Yes agreed with Noam, because of this only I'd mentioned the **in article** keyword in my answer

Comment: @Noam it can be done with `backdrop-filter` (which isn't quite `filter` but it still has filter in the name, lol) and z-index. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could always use `backdrop-filter` on a pseudo element, then a bit of z-index and you can create a class which is above the backdrop filter. See the example, any item with a class `.noFilter` will not be affected on hover

```css
article {
  padding: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
article::before {
  backdrop-filter: contrast(100%);

  content: "";
  display: block;

  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  
  transition: backdrop-filter 500ms 0ms ease-in-out;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  
  position: absolute;
  inset: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

div {
  background: #FCDBA3;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 200px;
  
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.noFilter {
  z-index: 4;
}

article:hover::before {
  backdrop-filter: contrast(150%);
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" />
  
  <div>Some content here</div>
  <div>Some content here</div>
  <div class="noFilter">Not affected by filter</div>
  <div>Some content here</div>
  <div class="noFilter">Not affected by filter</div>
  <div>Some content here</div>
  <div>Some content here</div>
</article>
```

Comment: In the article tag, there will be more tag. At least 20-30 tag. I just need to exclude only one tag. If I use the method then I have to capture every tag to set this style

Comment: What do you need to exclude? Can you update the snippet with more HTML and I'll see what I can do

Comment: @MuhammadZahidHasan I edited my snippet so that you can exclude elements from the filter by using a class. This is done with `backdrop-filter` on a pseudo element, not as a `filter` on on the article or children elements